# assigning values to objects in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

```
    package macroreader;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class MacroReader {

        public static Macro[] macroArray = new Macro[20];

        public static int macroID;

        public static BufferedReader br;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Macros.txt"));
            String currentLine;
            while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(currentLine.equalsIgnoreCase("#newmacro")) {
                    br.mark(1000);
                    createMacro();
                    br.reset();
                }
            }
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        }

    public static void createMacro() throws IOException {
        String currentLine;
        macroID = getEmptyMacro();
        while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null && !currentLine.equalsIgnoreCase("#newmacro")) {
            macroArray[macroID].readMacro(currentLine);
        }
        macroArray[macroID].inUse = true;
        macroArray[macroID].printData();
    }

    public static int getEmptyMacro() {
        for(int i = 0; i < macroArray.length; i++) {
            if(!macroArray[i].inUse) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

rather than assigning the values read from the file reader to the specified object in the array, in this case 'macroID', it assigns the values to all objects in the array

just edited in the whole file now but the issue is around the createMacro() void

here is my Macro class

```
package macroreader;

public class Macro {

    public static String key;
    public static String[] commands = new String[20];
    public static boolean inUse;

    public static void readMacro(String input) {
        if (!input.equals("")) {
            if (input.startsWith("key = ")) {
                key = input.substring(6);
                System.out.println("Key Value for Macro set to " + key);
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
                    if (commands[i] == null) {
                        commands[i] = input;
                        System.out.println("Command [" + input + "] assigned");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printData() {
        System.out.println("Macro Key: " + key);
        for(int i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
            if(commands[i] != null) {
                System.out.println(commands[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What data type is `macroArray` holding, and how is it defined? I'm not good at guessing. --- could it be that `inUse` is `static`?

Comment: public static Macro[] macroArray = new Macro[20];

Comment: The code you show can't possibly run to that point, because you are creating a new array without initializing its contents, so you will get a `NullPointerException` when trying to access the `inUse` field. (I tested it myself to be sure.) Please show the actual code you are working with. You don't have to include everything — just all of the code that works with `macroArray`.

Comment: Ah, it's static so you don't actually need any instances (and don't have any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected - your `inUse` is static, so it will always be the same for all instances of the class. As are your other class members.

Comment: I have changed the values from static.
However, now I can't seem to make use of the readMacro method in the Macro class

Comment: That's because jou need to us it on an instance: `Macro m = new Macro(); m.readMacro("inputstring...");`

Comment: Thank you mata, i would vote you up but apparently i need 15 repuation... well, atleast you know you helped me out! cheers

Answer (score 2):

The classic cause of "changing everything in an array" is if you have actually assigned *the same object* to every element in the array. We can't tell whether you're doing that because you didn't show us the initialization of `macroArray`, but it might be like:

```
Macro m = new Macro();
for (int i = 0; i < macroArray.length; i++) {
  macroArray[i] = m;
}
```

This will cause the results you describe. To fix it, create a separate object for every element of the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < macroArray.length; i++) {
  macroArray[i] = new Macro();
}
```

Comment: I have changed the values from static. However, now I can't seem to make use of the readMacro method in the Macro class